# how to view object attribute based on sql query?

Tags: oracle-adf

i have a view object that contains the following attributes

```
studentId
courseId
enrollDate
notes
```

and I have added 2 attributes, which are
studentName
courseName

and I want to select their values from another table(student,course) based on an SQL query.

i have tried to make a default value :SQL
and wrote the following query

```
select Course.courseName from Course where StudentCourse.CourseId = Course.id
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get their values from an SQL query. [This](http://www.exploreoracle.com/2010/09/07/using-transient-attribute-with-derived-from-sql-expression-in-jdeveloper-11g/) may help. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135583/how-to-assign-a-transient-value-as-a-default-value-to-another-attribute-in-view). Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584850/java-code-to-populate-an-transient-attribute-in-oracle-adf).